# How to reliably observe state updates in the Corda node?

Tags: blockchain, corda

The `ReconnectingCordaRPCOps.kt` [class](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-os-4.3/client/rpc/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/client/rpc/internal/ReconnectingCordaRPCOps.kt) available in Corda has the following note:

```
* Note: There is no guarantee that observations will not be lost.
```

1. What are the conditions in which a observation could get lost.
2. What would be a reliable way to continuously pull all state updates from a Corda node ?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the conditions in which a observation could get lost.

During a reconnection, the previous observer is automatically unsubscribed from the observable and re-subscribed after the connection is established again. As a result, if there are any events that had happened during this window between disconnection and reconnection, they will not be emitted to the observable.

> What would be a reliable way to continuously pull all state updates from a Corda node ?

Currently, the API for graceful reconnection provides two additional hooks `onDisconnect` and `onReconnect` (see docs [here](https://docs.corda.net/clientrpc.html#enabling-graceful-reconnection)), which can be used to perform some reconciliation to discover these updates that were not emitted. This could be achieved by querying the node's vault using a time window `[disconnection_event_time - safety_offset, reconnection_event_time + safety_offset]` and then discarding/deduplicating the events that have already been seen via the observable. The larger the `safety_offset` is, the more reliable this approach would be in not missing events.